# Updating multiple rows with information stored in text file

Tags: sql, db2

I have a comma delimited text file containing discrepancies across two different databases, and need to update one of the databases with information from the aforementioned text file.  The text file is in the following format:

```
ID        valueFromDb1    valueFromDb2
1             1234            4321
2             2345            5432
...            ...             ...
```

I need to go update a table by checking for the ID value, and where valueFromDb1 exists replace it with valueFromDb2.  There are around 11,000 rows that need to be updated.  Is there a way I can access the information in this text file directly through an sql query?  My other thought was to write a java program to do this for me, but I'm not convinced that is the easiest solution.

Comment: What platform are you on?  There are a number of iSeries commands that would help, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The article below demonstrates one way to read a text file in MS SQL Server by using xp_cmdshell. In order for it to work the file has to be on one of the drives of the server. Once you have the file loaded into a table variable (which is what the code in the article will do) you should be able to do the joins and updates pretty easily. Let us know if you need any other help.

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/read-text-file-using-xp_cmdshell.aspx